# Why is the event object different coming from jQuery bind vs. addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Why is it when I use the jQuery bind the event object I get back is different from the event object I get back using `addEventListener`?

The event object resulting from this jQuery bind does not have the `targetTouches` array (among other things) but the event from the `addEventListener` does.  Is it me or is something not right here?

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $("#test").bind("touchmove", function (event) {
        console.log(event.targetTouches[0].pageX);
        // targetTouches is undefined
    });
});
```

vs.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    var foo = document.querySelectorAll('#test')
    foo[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
        console.log(event.targetTouches[0].pageX);
        // returns the correct values
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code involving the creation of the targetTouches variable?

Comment: @bobthabuilda: `targetTouches` is a property of the `touch` events that are available if I remember correctly, only on Safari/WebKit (really common on iPhone apps).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because jQuery uses its own [Event model](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

jQuery simply copies and normalizes *some properties* from the original event, to the event object that you get as the first argument of the handler.

The copied properties are based on the [DOM Level 3 Events Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/ecma-script-binding.html).

To get the original event object, you can:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $("#test").bind("touchmove", function (event) {
        var e = event.originalEvent;
        console.log(e.targetTouches[0].pageX);
    });
});
```

The `originalEvent` property is accessible and it will work, but is not documented, you can see how it's set behind the scenes in the [`jQuery.Event`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L548) constructor.

Comment: The `originalEvent` property is documented at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ under “special properties”.

Comment: @Mathias: Thanks, I'll update the post later, the property wasn't documented [back in 2010](http://replay.web.archive.org/20100827151056/http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: Sure, I was just adding the link to your answer for future reference now that it finally is documented (not sure when exactly that happened). Thanks for editing your post :)