# iOS "done" callback button on html5 video for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html

I got several html5 video players on a page, I'm having problems trying to fire a function after the user taps "done" on the Iphone/Ipad native player.

I'm losing my mind on this, I though it would be simple.

The JS:

```
$(".mediaplayer").click(function(){
    var elVideo = $(this).find('video');
    var elID = elVideo.data("id");
    elVideo.get(0).play();
    elVideo.attr('poster', 'assets/poster_loading.gif');    
    elVideo.on("ended", function() {
        window.location.href = 'redirect.php?id=' + elID;
    });
    elVideo.addEventListener('webkitendfullscreen', function() {
        alert("boom");
    }, false);  
 });
```

The HTML (it repeats several times):

```
<div class="asset" data-url="49">
                <div>
                    <div class="asset-name">Plan Test</div>
                    <div class="asset-detail-toggle-icon">
                        <span class="icon-circle-down"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="asset-info" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="asset-author">Author: Circe</div>
                    <div>Descripción: Colombia </div>
                    <!--player-->                        
                    <div class="player">
                        <div class="mediaplayer">
                            <video poster="assets/poster.jpg" controls="" preload="none" data-id="49">
                                <source src="assets/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                <source src="assets/sample.webm" type="video/webm">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- player -->                          
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for .bind()

```
elVideo.bind('webkitendfullscreen', function() {
  alert("boom");
});
```

Comment: Correct, and here are some extended reading about bind vs addEventListener: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863216/why-is-the-event-object-different-coming-from-jquery-bind-vs-addeventlistener

Comment: The idea is when the video is finished, redirect the user to another page.
I changed to bind and its not working.
The alert its not showing up after I hit the "done" button

Comment: Something is happening. After I tap the video poster, the video runs and I hit done. After this done tap. I tap again on the poster and the alert is fired! odd.

Answer (score 1):

I Finally got it working, maybe not an elegant solution, but its ok. I had to "hide" the big play button on iOS, and add a statement to the JS.

The JS

```
$(".mediaplayer").click(function(){
        var elVideo = $(this).find('video');
        var elID = elVideo.data("id");
        elVideo.get(0).play();
        elVideo.attr('poster', 'assets/poster_loading.gif');
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {  
            elVideo.bind('webkitendfullscreen', function() {
                window.location.href = 'plan_pregunta.php?id=' + elID;
            });
        } else {    
            elVideo.on("ended", function() {
                window.location.href = 'plan_pregunta.php?id=' + elID;
            });
        }
    });
```

The CSS

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```